# Sql trigger parent child

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am trying to work out the best way to create a trigger but I have hit a brick wall using sql server 2008 
I wish to create a central table that stores all telephone numbers (number) this should contain all customer numbers from the customer table.
Numbers has a child table numbercustomer that links a number to one or more customers.
My Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [Campaign].[Number](
    [NumberID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Number] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdated] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [Pk_Number] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [NumberID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [Campaign].[NumberCustomer](
    [CustomerNumberID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NumberID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CustomerNumber] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CustomerNumberID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [Crm].[Customer](
    [CustomerID] [int] IDENTITY(30000,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [MobileNumber] [varchar](11) NULL,
    [LandlineNumber] [varchar](11) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__Customer__8CB286B91CF15040] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CustomerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I would like the trigger to check the number table and insert the number if it is not present. The second part of the trigger shuld then check and insert if not present the link to the customer.
I can get the number table to update with trigger as follows bbut I am concered about performance.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Crm].[Customer_Number_Updated] ON [Crm].[Customer]
 AFTER Update, INSERT
 NOT FOR REPLICATION AS
 SET NoCount On 

DECLARE 
  @AuditTime DATETIME, 
  @IsDirty BIT
SET @AuditTime = GetDate()

SET @IsDirty = 0

  Begin Try
    INSERT INTO 
        [Campaign].[Number]([Number])
    select 
        number 
    from 
    (
    Select
        i.MobileNumber as number
    From 
        inserted i
    join 
        deleted d
    on 
        i.CustomerID = d.CustomerID 
    and
    isnull(i.MobileNumber ,'') <> isnull(d.MobileNumber,'')
    UNION
    Select
        i.LandlineNumber as number
    From 
        inserted i
    join 
        deleted d
    on 
        i.CustomerID = d.CustomerID 
    and
    isnull(i.LandlineNumber ,'') <> isnull(d.LandlineNumber,'')
    UNION
    Select
        i.AlternateContactNumber as number
    From 
        inserted i
    join 
        deleted d
    on 
        i.CustomerID = d.CustomerID 
    and
    isnull(i.AlternateContactNumber ,'') <> isnull(d.AlternateContactNumber,'')
    ) as nums
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 
                *
            FROM 
                [Campaign].[Number] cn
            WHERE 
                cn.Number = nums.number 
        )
End try
 Begin Catch 
 IF ERROR_NUMBER() <> 2627
   DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000), @ErrorSeverity INT, @ErrorState INT;
   SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();  
   SET @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(); 
   SET @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();  
   RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage,@ErrorSeverity,@ErrorState) with log;
 End Catch

GO
```

Any help would be much appreciated?

Rob

Comment: **Numbers has a child table numbercustomer that links a number to one or more customers.** That seems weird. A number will be shared among multiple customers? Are you sure it isn't the other way around, e.i. a customer can have multiple numbers?

Comment: A customer can and does have one or more numbers perhaps i should have said we are trying to use this for reporting and in this case its many to many really

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your code works, but you're just looking for optimalization? Perhaps you should make this more clear in your question if that's the case.

Comment: My code works for number but i cant work out how to adjust it to also check and enter into the child table

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger works for UPDATE but not for INSERT: you are joining DELETED and INSERTED and when you insert new records, there is nothing in deleted.
You should do an INSERT and an  UPDATE in your trigger, or do a MERGE.

Here is the code with an insert and an update (only the code in the try block)

The insert do a left join with deleted and check that the id is null (anti semi join, equivalent to no texists).

The update do a inner join with inserted to check for update records only

```
  Begin Try

    -- insert new records
    INSERT INTO 
        [Campaign].[Number]([Number])
    select 
        i.MobileNumber
    from inserted i
    left join deleted d on i.customerid = d.customerid
    where d.customerid is null -- new records (no deleted record)
    and not exists( select Number from [Campaign].[Number] c where c.number = i.MobileNumber)
    -- union the same for LAndLineNumber
    -- union the same for AlternateNumber

    -- update existing number
    update [Campaign].[Number] 
        set Number = i.MobileNumber
        -- set LandLineNumber too
        -- and AlternateNumber
    from [Campaign].[Number] n
        left join deleted d on d.MobileNumber = n.Number
        inner join inserted i on i.CustomerId = d.CustomerId

End try
```